# PySpark Partition Dataframe created from HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I'm fetching data from HiveContext and creating DataFrame. To achieve performance benefits I want to partition DF before applying join operation. How to parition data on 'ID' column and then apply Join on 'ID'

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
hiveCtx = HiveContext(spark)
df1 = hiveCtx.sql("select id,name,address from db.table1")
df2 = hiveCtx.sql("select id,name,marks from db.table2")
```

Need to perform following operarions on data

1. Dataframe partitionBy 'ID'
2. Join by 'ID'

Answer (score 0):

You can use repartition.

Refer spark docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=repartition#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition

Based on your data size, choose the no.of.partition.

```
df1= df1.repartition(7, "id")
```

Comment: This operation just repartitions my data , or while performing join on my dataset there will be optimized Join condition. Meaning , it will refer only specific partition for id=1 , instead of going through entire data ?   Because partitionBy divides my data to disk in directory structure   , but repartition doesn't.